# Showing identify results in dijit/tabcontainer in CMV?

Tags: configurable-map-viewer, identify

I want to use dijit/Layout/Tabcontainer to show results in identify.js. It can't show the Tabcontainer correctly.

The result of the infowindow is as the link, it seems there is CSS file conflicts.

I only change the "identify.js" file of the original one. The code of my changed part is as below.

[image: issues in the tabcontainer]

```
    identifyCallback: function (identifiedlayers, responseArray) {
        var fSet = [];
        array.forEach(responseArray, function (response, i) {
             console.log("valve Chamber");
            var ref = identifiedlayers[i].ref;
            array.forEach(response, function (result) {
                result.feature.geometry.spatialReference = this.map.spatialReference; //temp workaround for ags identify bug. remove when fixed.
                if (result.feature.infoTemplate === undefined) {
                  //***************I change this part start **************//
                  //  var infoTemplate = this.getInfoTemplate(ref, null, result);
                    var infoTemplate=new InfoTemplate();
                    var tc = new TabContainer({ style: "width:300px;height:300px;"

                    }, domConstruct.create("div"));
                    // Display attribute information.
                    var cp1 = new ContentPane({
                        title: "tab1",
                        content: "substation"
                    });                        // Display a dojo pie chart for the male
                    var cp2 = new ContentPane({
                        title: "tab2"
                    });
                    var cp3=new ContentPane({
                        title: "tab3"
                    });
                    tc.addChild(cp1);
                    tc.addChild(cp2);
                    tc.addChild(cp3);
                    infoTemplate.setContent(tc.domNode);

             //***********I change this part End *************//
                    if (infoTemplate) {
                        result.feature.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                fSet.push(result.feature);
            }, this);
        }, this);
        this.map.infoWindow.setFeatures(fSet);
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who having the same problem, i accidently found the solution for this

add this >>> **useMenu : false, useSlider : false**

as shown here >>>

```
var tc = new TabContainer({ style: "width:300px;height:300px;", 
                useMenu : false, useSlider : false
                },
```

this will remove the buttons from TabContainer

Comment: @BaohuaChu .. you can thank me by tick this answer and set your vote  :)